# Why is $V_{4}$ the semi direct product of $Z_{2}$× $Z_{2}$

Tags: group-theory, products

I'm trying to understand what is a semi direct product , so by the definition semi-direct product of G , I'd need two groups , $N$ and $H$ , where :

1. $H∩N$ = {e}
2. $H \cdot N$ = $G$

If $H=N=Z_{2}$  , then : $Z_{2}∩Z_{2}≠{e}$ .

Which contradicts $H∩N$ = {e} . So what am I missing here ?

Why does $V_{4}$ is indeed the semi direct product of $Z_{2}$× $Z_{2}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: For the uninitiated: what is $V_4$?

Comment: @Mike: Klein four-group , see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group

Comment: Isn't it in deed the direct product? Because there are not that much automorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: Actually, the Vierergruppe $V_4$ is the _direct_ product of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$. A direct product is a particular case of a semidirect product.

Comment: Silly solution: We know that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ both have order four and are non-isomorphic (as $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$). However, there are precisely two groups of order four, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $V_4$ (alternatively this line can read "Note that $V_4$ is non-cyclic"). Thus, $V_4\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, as required. I cannot give you a better answer as you haven't told us what you have for definition of $V_4$...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, here, the idea could be stated more concisely this way:

Show that there exist subgroups $H,K\leq V_4$ such that $H,K\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $V_4$ is the semi-direct product of $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you consider the presentation of  Klein four-group $V$ as follows, then the problematic points get solved easily. This is one presentation of it: $$V=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=1,(ab)^2=1\rangle$$ The relation $(ab)^2=1$ can be regarded as $abab=1$ or $aba^{-1}=b^{-1}=b$. It shows that if we set $H=\langle b\rangle$ then $H$ is normal in $V$ (However, we already know that this group is abelian and maybe we don't need this result anymore). Now $V/H$ is defined as $$V/H=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=1,(ab)^2=1, b=1\rangle=\langle a\mid a^2\rangle=K$$ so $K$ is a complement of $H$ in $G$ and since $H\cap K=1$ and $HK=V$ so we have $$V=H\times K\cong\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$$

Comment: Even though this is in fact a direct product you only showed it is a semidirect product so you should write $\rtimes$ or $\ltimes$ but not $\times$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Yes. In the first step we may write it in this group as the semi-direct, but; when two subgroups are both normal in the group semi-direct is changed to meaning of direct product.

Comment: Nice work, Babak! ${+}_+^++_+^++$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy :-)